# What is the best way of generating java class from a WSDL url for android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl2code

I have a SOAP Web Service that i want to parse and use in my android project. I have read that there is a website that auto generates the java classes by importing the url (wsl2code) but it seems to have flaws. Additionally the sample they provide is not working. What is the best and correct way of generating java classes from a WSDL url for my android project?

Answer (score 0):

Use ksoal2 library for soap service which is light weight for android but the think you have to create service call manually

Comment: is there a way of auto generating the java classes of the web service just like wsdl2code does??

Comment: that won't work because i need to use the whole service, it will be pointless to just do service calls per method

Comment: Sorry but I also suffered from same situation where I created 16 service calls manually

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I have used the service of wsdl2code http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx . Just some information regarding that, it has some limitations like

- Don't Support byref Variables , in class
- Don't Support Boolean& Variables , in class
- Don't Support Int64& Variables , in class
- Methods that are boolean or a custom class are turned to void and must be modified manually

Overall though this website saved me since it would take me a while to create the classes I needed by myself. It might have taken me a while to modify the classes but still saved a lot of time.